# Mongo Dart find documents if a property array doesn't contain an object

Tags: flutter, dart, mongo-dart

Here is a example where I'm creating a pipeline to a mongoDB where I'm quering for a documents where 'recieved_by' array contains a provided user.id.

`

```
final pipeline = AggregationPipelineBuilder()
        .addStage(Match(where.within('fullDocument.received_by', user.id).map['\$query']));
```

`
How to do opposite thing. I need documents where 'received_by' array DOESN'T CONTAIN provided value (user.id).

Thank you